# Downloading sample data from magento in AWS ec2 instance

Tags: magento2, aws, sample-data, data, magento2-cloud

Iam new to AWS and Magento as well and iam trying to download Sample Magento data in my EC2 instance . I have installed magento in EC2 . When  I tried using `bin/magento sampledata:deploy` in my EC2 , i got the error message as bin/magento not found. Can anybody tell what are the steps to download sample data in my ec2?

Comment: You use localhost xampp??

Comment: No , AWS EC2 instance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use it via nginx or apache and then you need to go to /var/www/html directory
after that you need to run this commands

wget https://magento.com/tech-resources/downloads/index/download/file_id/2875/category_id/2341/

and then unzip 
by using unzip command.

and after that use magento guide to host he app.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Once you run this command:

> php bin/magento sampledata:deploy

then you need to follow couple of more steps as well:

After running the above command, it will ask about URL authentication to repo.magento.com. You have to enter a username and password.

Upgrade the setup by running the following CLI command:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Next, just run the following commands one by one:

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile php bin/magento
>   setup:static-content:deploy -f

However, if you get any memory error message after running a command to install Magento sample data, then update the command as follows:

> php -d memory_limit=2G bin/magento sampledata:deploy

To understand these steps into more detail follow this guide: https://magenticians.com/install-magento-2-sample-data/

I hope it will work for you. If you still face any issues feel free to ping me.

Comment: Thank you for the steps !